# How to get two minimum values ​from a price column (database). [Laravel]

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm doing an online store and I have a "sale" section. In this section I want to place two products with the minimum price. I can get one product using the min () function, but I do not understand how to get two minimum values ​​from the database.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Post your context where you used `min()` function so that others can get better understanding and answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use it like the for getting two minimum values

```
$sale = Sale::orderBy('price','asc')->take(2)->get();
```